# sort(ASCX) или sort(ASC(X1))

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Что такое `array.sort(ASCX)`? 
Что в данном случае означает `ASCX`? 
Или `array.sort(ASC(X1));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASCX` - это функция сравнения

Целью функции сравнения является определение альтернативного порядка сортировки.

Функция сравнения должна возвращать отрицательное, ноль или положительное значение в зависимости от аргументов:

```
var ASCX = function (a, b) {return a-b}
```

Когда функция `sort()` сравнивает два значения, они отправляют значения в функцию сравнения и сортируют значения в соответствии с возвращаемым (отрицательным, нулевым, положительным) значением.